# Storing LVM encryption key on network share

Tags: networking, disk-encryption, ubuntu

I want to encrypt all my LVM LV's and have them automatically unlocked on boot using a keyfile available on my network. I can make the files available by SMB, NFS, HTTPS, etc.

I have Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 with LVM setup for the main drive and a seperate VG consisting for 3 hard drives organized into a single LV. I want to encrypt everything except the /boot.

EDIT: I guess a question might be more helpful

I want to know how I would access the keyfile from a network share automatically at boot. Would it be as simple as placing the network path somewhere or would I need to download it, decrypt, and delete it? As I said I can share it with just about any network filesystem

Comment: Was there a question in there?

Comment: Sorry, I do that a lot. I want to know how I would access the keyfile from a network share automatically at boot. Would it be as simple as placing the network path somewhere or would I need to download it, decrypt, and delete it?